# Why isn't my bread machine making any bread?

Tags: bread

I bought a new 1-pound bread machine. After many tries, the machine has yet to make any bread. I am using all raw ingredients, as the local supermarket does not sell any bread machine mixes.

- I tried following some of the recipes in the included recipe book and marketing video, which requires that the the flour and yeast be placed in the machine last, on top of the liquid ingredients.
- I also tried these [Bread Machine Bread](http://allrecipes.com/video/710/bread-machine-bread/detail.aspx?e11=bread%20machine&e8=Quick%20Search&event10=1&event8=1&prop24=SR_Showcase&e7=Home%20Page&soid=sr_showcase_1) steps from [Allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com/), which asks for the yeast, 40°C water, and sugar to be placed in the machine first, to sit for 10 minutes, but I used the ingredient measurements described in the machine's recipe book, as my machine is only 1 lb.
- Some recipes on-line call for "bread machine yeast", but I can only find "dry active yeast".

After the clock reached 0, I opened the machine and always found either: (a) the ingredients just compacted and cracked, but dry and not mixed up or (b) a yellow, jelly-like blob, somewhat baked, but still soft, with unmixed, still dry and powdery flour at the top.

- What do I need to do to get my bread machine to work?
- Do I need to mix the ingredients before putting them into the machine?

Comment: Is the paddle attached to the bottom of the well? The little mixing arm that tends to stay in the bread after it bakes?

Comment: If the answer I posted doesn't immediately make sense, please tell us the brand and model number of your machine.

Comment: Inside the machine there is a bucket (that can be pulled out). At the bottom inside of the bucket is a paddle, that can turn around freely. It seems attached well and hasn't come off along with the unfinished bread. Model: Midea EHS10AH-PY.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding that manual, but I want you to try something. With the machine fully assembled but empty, turn it on. If you can open the lid while it's working, check to see that that paddle is spinning. If it stops when the lid is open, put something in it that will make noise but not hurt anything, like a handful of dried beans.

Comment: The very first thing the machine should do is make that paddle spin. That's what mixes and kneads the dough.

Comment: Does it look like [this](http://www.usave.com.hk/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=2224&zenid=bcf28b6237dc2279162ae26dfce117c6)?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that picture. Okay, I turned it on, following the steps in the manual, and then opened it. It is not spinning at all, in fact, I think I've never heard the machine making any sound at all. Perhaps I need to return it?

Comment: It sounds like there is something very wrong with the machine and and it should be returned. Do you have a camera? Can you post a picture of the inside of the machine? I also want you to look carefully, is there any other place to attach a paddle like the one we are discussing? At least in older machines, these paddles are removable, it's easy to accidentally forget it and end up with "dough" just like you are describing

Comment: @Village: Note that the machine may only begin to spin after an hour or so: mine started with an hour of doing nothing because it needed to give the ingredients some time to reach room temperature. So you could turn on the machine and stay in the room most of the time, see whether it makes any sound. The paddle will probably be working only partly or not at all...

Comment: @village aside from the actual problem (sorry, but I have no idea about that): Don't use 40°C hot water. It's way too much for yeast, it will already kill part of it. Handmade breads are best with cold water and long rising times, but if your machine uses short rising, you could warm your water to 30-32 Celsius. You'll need the manual or experimentation to figure out the lowest temperature which still gives you a decent rise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you may be missing a very important piece.

[image: 1] **this**

**belongs here:** [image: 2]